# nested classes anonymous classes

Tags: java, oop, nested-class

```
public class A {
  protected int x;
  public A(int x) { this.x = x; }
  public void g() { System.out.println(x); }
  public void h() { System.out.println(x + 10); }
}
public class B {
  public void f() {
  (new A(2) {
    public void g() {
      h();
    }
   }).g();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new B().f();
}
```

Can some body help me understanding this line in code:

```
new A(2) { public void g() {h();} }).g();
```

I don't understand if he define a anonymous class here with A ?? and how in the  anonymous he can refer to A.h() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He creates an anonymous class and also overwrites `g()`. It's the same like when you use `Runnable` and `override` run.

```
(new A(2) { public void g() {h();} }).g();
```

means

```
class C extends A
{
    public C()
    {
        super(2);
    }

    @Override
    public void g()
    {
        this.h();
    }
}

(new C()).g();  // or C c = new C(); c.g();
```

Answer (score 4):

This line creates a no-named class that overrides the parent class's `g()` method so that it does a new thing: invoking `h()`. However at once it calls the `g()` method on this no-named class at once.

Comment: so A(2) here is not the name of the new class, it is a parent class for the non name class not overriding A ? please correct me

Comment: A(2) means that this new anonymous class is instantiated with the constructor argument 2 at once.

Answer (score 2):

The line you quoted defines a new anonymous class that `extends A` and `Overrides` `g()` and then invokes it.

Since the anonymous class extends A, it embodies the definition of `h()` so it can be invoked